# How to add array of labels to windows form in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I add these label array named tile to my form? 
Also the properties of actual label appearing in the form should change as i change the properties in the code.
Can anybody help me out with this?

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using   
System.ComponentModel; using System.Data; using System.Drawing;
using    System.Linq; using System.Text; using
System.Threading.Tasks; using    System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Piano_Tiles 
{    

       public partial class Form1 : Form    
       {
       public Label[] tile = new Label[4];

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
           {
               tile[i] = new Label();
               tile[i].Height = 200;
               tile[i].Width = 100;
               tile[i].Left = (i % 3) * 100;
               tile[i].Top = i * 200;
               tile[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
               tile[i].Visible = true;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are, you should add control to control collection of the form:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            tile[i] = new Label();
            tile[i].Height = 200;
            tile[i].Width = 100;
            tile[i].Left = (i % 3) * 100;
            tile[i].Top = i * 200;
            tile[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
            tile[i].Visible = true;
            Controls.Add(tile[i]);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Key feature you've missed: any control you're trying to add to the form, should be also added to form's `Controls` collection, otherwise it will not be displayed by form.

So just add `Controls.Add(tile[i]);` at the end of your loop.